# Installing Software has encountered a Error for CLOVER plugin

Tags: eclipse, clover

I tried installing Clover Plugin but i am getting an error as :-

Installing Software has encountered a problem

Error Message :-

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://update.atlassian.com/eclipse/clover/plugins/com.atlassian.clover.eclipse.core_4.0.0.v20140711000000.jar.
Read timed out

How to solve this issue.
I followed the steps given in link :

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/1.+Clover+for+Eclipse+in+10+minutes

Comment: Have you tried again after some time? It could have been a temporary problem with a network.

Comment: In case you have problems downloading from update site, you can always try installation from a ZIP archive: http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/download